# What to do when DataAdapter.Update return 1 but the database is unchanged?

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

I want to insert a new row into a msaccess table using the following code.

```
class MachineDataTable : DataTable
{
    public MachineDataTable()
    {
        Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ID", typeof(int)));
        Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)));
        PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { Columns["ID"] };
    }
    ...
}
```

The following code work as expected:

```
da.ExecuteNonQuery(@"CREATE TABLE Machine (
            ID LONG NOT NULL,
            Name TEXT NOT NULL
        )");
```

The DataAdapter InsertCommand is created using:

```
DbCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "Machine";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.TableDirect;
da.InsertCommand = cmd;
```

Then I try to insert one row.

```
MachineDataTable table = new MachineDataTable();
DataRow row = table.NewRow();
row["ID"] = 1234; 
row["Name"] = "Name";
table.Add(row);
int n = da.Update(table);
//n == 1
```

The Update call return 1 (row updated) and no exceptions.
When I look in the database using MsAccess there is no row inserted.

Comment: Is there perhaps some transaction involved that is getting rolled back?

Comment: Are there any rows in the `Machine` table at all?

Comment: @Simen No, the table is empty before and after.

Comment: @Marc, as far as I know I have not initiated any transactions.

Comment: @phq: And you can insert rows in the table with the MSAccess client

Comment: @Simen, Yes and I can also do It using a direct SQL query using da.ExecuteNonQuery

Comment: @phq: You don't have a sql server database available. If you ran the code on a SQL server target you could investigate the SQL instructions using the SQL profiler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, `TableDirect` is essentially issuing a `SELECT` query over the table, and then (following the "If execution of this command returns rows" notes from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.insertcommand.aspx)), these existing rows are being merged. It isn't doing an insert/update. Maybe consider a command builder [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tf579hcz.aspx) ?

(caveat: I never, ever, ever use DataAdapter - this is based purely on my interpretation of MSDN; it could easily be wrong)

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Have you remembered to actually call the `MachineTable()` method on the `table` object of type `MyDataTable` from somewhere?</strike>

It seems like maybe you intended for the `MachineTable()` method to be the constructor of the `MyDataTable` class which it isn't.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion from my part, I have changed all My to Machine to make the code consistent.

The MachineTable() should be the constructor in my example.